# Netty ObjectDecoder ReferenceCounts

Tags: java, netty

If I have simple pipelines for my inbound and outbound handlers with only logging and ObjectEncoder/Decoder (and my own inbound handler which is downstream of the ObjectDecoder), do I need to worry about reference counted objects leaking memory? I wouldn't think so, but the heap in my application is growing faster than I'd expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope you not need to worry about if you only have this handlers. Take a heap dump and see what is in there to get a better understanding what's going on.